# How to select a differnent audio ouput per application in archlinux

Tags: audio, gnome, arch

I want chrome to use a separate dac from everything else.

I know you can do that in windows using the advanced settings. What about arch?

I am using the Gnome DE and arch OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [pulseaudio](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=pulseaudio) and [pavucontrol](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/pavucontrol/) then enable and start pulseaudio with

```
systemctl enable pulseaudio
systemctl start pulseaudio
```

Then open pavucontrol, you have to have the applications you want to manage open, you can then chose the output device for each application.